# MVC global exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-mvc-5, global-asax, application-error

I am coding an MVC 5 internet application, and I have a question in regards to handling exceptions globally.

I have my `Application_Error` setup in my `global.asax` file. This caters to errors such as `404` `HttpExceptions`.

How can I send all errors that occur in a controller to the `Application_Error` function? An example is the following exception:

> System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous
>   Request.Form value was detected from the client (name="").

I have written a `OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)` for my controller, but am not sure on how to get the `Application_Error` function to handle these errors. Do I need to pass the exception from the `OnException` function, or is this the wrong approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to handle exception, you write code in OnException and mark ExceptionHandled as true, if you don't use this method or don't mark it as handled it goes to Application_Error (that should be used only for ASP.NET failures logging but not for your application exception handling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a global filter by adding the following class to your App_Start folder:-

```
public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());

        }
    }
```

HandleErrorAttribute can be replaced with your own custom Exception Filter.

All you then need to do is make sure you add the following line of code to the App_Start method of your Gloabal.asax :-

```
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            //AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            //RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have created a global filter, but is it possible to call the Application_Error function from the global filter? Should this be done, or should the Application_Error be only for exceptions not from a controller?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using some kind of http-module which gives me exactly what you are asking for:

```
public class MyModule : IHttpModule {

    public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
        context.Error += OnRequestError;
    }

    private void OnRequestError(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;

        var error = context.Error;
        if (error == null)
            return;
        var errorType = error.GetType();
        if (errorType == typeof(HttpException))
            // do something

        // this is what you are looking for
        if (errorType = typeof(HttpRequestValidationException))
            // do something, whatever you want
        // works for me, so should work to you too
    }
}
```

To get the module to work, you can use `web.config` or `DynamicModuleHelper`:

- Install `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure` and `WebActivatorEx` via `nuget`
- Add a `Bootstrapper` class to your project
- Register module at `PreApplicationStartMethod`

Sample:

```
// File: Bootstrapper.cs (contains class Bootstrapper)

using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;
using WebActivatorEx;
using WhatEver.It.Is;

[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Bootstrapper), "Bootstrap")]

namespace WhatEver.It.Is {
    public class Bootstrapper {
        public static void Bootstrap() {
            // Do what do you need just before the application get started
            // like registering modules, etc...
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(MyModule));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I get the module to work? I have added the code, and the following in the web.config:     <add name="MyModule" type="MyModule" />